# Magic links para Stack Overflow en Español

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, comentarios, magic-links

Aún no funciona el [**magic link**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-links?sort=votes&pageSize=50) `[es.so]`. *Please, turn it on!*

Para quienes no saben lo que es, añadiré un comentario abajo con el siguiente texto, los de SOes no renderizan:

> [meta]; [es.so]; [pt.so]; [ru.so]; [meta.se]

---

#### Comportamiento esperado:

`[es.so]` tendría que generar [Stack Overflow en español](http://es.stackoverflow.com) en toda la red de Stack Exchange.

Comment: [meta]; [es.so]; [pt.so]; [ru.so]; [meta.se]

Comment: Quizás los enlaces mágicos no funcionen en la beta privada.

Comment: @brasofilo Está bien que no funcione `[meta]` acá (en meta), pero sí funciona en en el sitio principal, al menos ahora (así como acá funciona `[main] =`[main] en meta pero no en el principal). Y adhiero totalmente a que se implemente `[es.so]` en toda la red de SE

Answer (score 2):

> De la respuesta de [@Oded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140505/oded) en [Magic link for Stack Overflow in Spanish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283268/304899)

`[es.so]` ya fue implementado y funciona en los comentarios del sitio (31/8/16).

Y a partir del del 15/11/16 también funciona en el chat.